# How can I stop create react app fast refresh on change to only act on save?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, compilation, create-react-app

I'm not sure how can I make Fast_Refresh only activate the compilation on save rather than on any change made to source, as I'm typing;

at the moment its activated on any change without even needing a file save, and thats a little annoying for some large components, as I'm making a change it breaks the interface.
I thouhgt it's watching filesystem, but something else is triggering the compilation as I'm typing...

I am using vscode, react project + typescript created using create-react-app using react "^17.0.2" on a large scale project.